# Filter out values from List based on strings using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have to filter out values from the List (`include` and `exclude`) which contains string values based upon the values which I am getting in variable `requestedData`.

In the variable `requestedData` we have data as `['student', 'teacher']`

```
include = ['student']

exclude = ['dentist+teacher']
```

Basically `+` in the exclude means `AND`, by that it means that user is both dentist and teacher.
Same data with `+` can appear in `include`.

In the variable `sections` am trying to get data which present in both `requestedData` and `include` and we remove it if its part of `exclude`. But before checking for `exclude` values we need to parse `dentist+teacher` to remove `+` and check `dentist` and `teacher` individually. So basically in the above example since we don't have both `dentist` and `teacher` in `requestedData` only `student` will be returned to `sections` as it is in both `include` and `requestedData`.

Same thing need to be done for `include` if it has data with `+`.

In the below solution I am able to check data without `+`. I was wondering how I can parse `+` and check for `AND` condition.

```
val sections = this.data
        .map { prof ->
            prof.variations.filter { career ->
                (career.exclude.isEmpty() || career.exclude.intersect(requestedData).isEmpty()) &&
                    (career.include.isEmpty() || career.include.intersect(requestedData).isNotEmpty())
            }
        }
        .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
        .map { Section(it) }
```